# Как посчитать сумму пауз за день в который это происходило с учетом idman SQL запросом?

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как посчитать суму разницы времени за день в который это происходило с учетом idman.

[image: Sql таблица]

Запрос

```
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(timediff(a.finish, a.start)))) as 
pausesum, a.idman, a.date from pause a group by a.idman
```

Вывод[image: Вывод]

Comment: Приведите вопрос в порядок, в заголовке одно, в вопросе другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5f076/1

Я не знаю какую СУБД вы используюте, сделал в PostgreSQL. Я думаю, можно легко адаптирвоать под другие. Просто учитывайте дату и id менеджера в `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
d.idmanager,
d.workdate,
sum(d.stop - d.start)
FROM docs AS d
GROUP BY d.idmanager, d.workdate
```

Answer (score 0):

SQl запрос и вывод в MySQL Workbench

```
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(timediff(a.finish, a.start)))) as 
pausesum, a.idman, a.date from pause a group by a.idman,a.Date
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Вот вариант:

```
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(timediff(a.finish, a.start)))) as pausesum
from pause a
order by a.Workdate
```